# nginx rewrite group.php to /group/

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am currently battling with the existing documentation of the rewrite rule in nginx. I have a hard time finding anyone else who have done this aswell.

What I want is rather simple. When I visit http://mypage.com/group.php I want to be redirected to http://mypage.com/group/. I want it to read group.php ofcourse when I visit /group/

I've played around a bit with locations in my server config but never got it to work.

```
location /group/ {
     rewrite ^/group(.*) group.php
}
```

I can't seem to get this rule.

Comment: Is it only this single folder `group` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. It redirects `/group.php` to `/group/`
2. Rewrite everything in /group/ to /group/group.php

This assumes `group.php` exists in `/group/group.php`.

```
rewrite ^/group\.php$ /group/ redirect;
rewrite ^/group/ /group/group.php last;
```

Comment: I just put it inside the server block?

Comment: Yes. Under server block.

Comment: This returns 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @user3218338 please, help others to help you. check the logs.

Comment: Sorry, here is the log

2014/01/21 13:11:54 [error] 18792#0: *6 rewrite or internal redirection cycle wh                                        ile internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: mypage.com, request: "GET /group/ HTTP/1.1", host: "mypage.com                                       "

Comment: I seem to get these errors no matter what page I visit so I dont think it is relevant?

Comment: Do you have another rewrite that redirects everything to index.html?

Comment: I had a location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html } which I commented out. Now I get 0 errors in error.log and 404 instead of forbidden on the code from @Michael Tabolsky

Comment: Oh I see. I keep all my files in the project root and not in /group/. Can I make it read from the project root instead of /group/group.php?

Comment: Does the file group.php exist in /group/group.php? If it doesn't exist, it will go to index.html as declared in try_files.

Comment: Change to rewrite ^/group/ /group.php last;

Comment: Yeah, I do not want that file structure. I keep all my files together with index.php, is this possible with this setup? 

I saw you edit. Ill try it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45710/discussion-between-user3218338-and-hongtat)